# What are vector norms used for?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, general-topology, vectors, normed-spaces

I'm currently working with a computer science problem that requires me to build vectors that can return their own norms. Based on [Wolfram Alpha's](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VectorNorm.html) description, I think I have an idea of how this is accomplished for the simple $L^2$ norm ($\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}$, and so on) required by the exercise, but I've no notion of what this is actually useful for or why I would want to find it, outside of it being required by the exercise.

Any insight is appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by a vector "that can return its own norm"? The language of computer science is very mysterious to me...

Comment: @goblin a vector is an object in a programming language, which knows its properties, like coordinates and norm...

Comment: Yeah, sorry @goblin, that was just meant to be background, it wasn't really pertinent to what I was actually asking. As gt6989b said, I was creating an object intended to hold vectors (using another 'array' object as a property of the vector object to hold individual vector 'x' values), which had the ability to access the vector it was storing, return it to various functions, and make various of computations on the vector, including conducting arithmetic with any vectors passed to it and computing and returning its own vector norm. I just didn't know what the norm was used for mathematically.

Comment: @Brad, hmmm okay. So you hand the "vector" the query "I want to know your norm" and it speaks back to you: "my norm is 2.87" type-thing? Or have I completely misunderstood you? By the way the whole object-oriented thing isn't widely understood by mathematicians (unless they have a background in programming), so maybe include a bit more explanation any time you want to include OOP language/concepts in a math question.

Comment: @goblin there's not quite that much interface built in, but that's the basic idea. In the actual code you could do something like 
`var myVector = new Vector([1, 2, 3]);
console.log(myVector.norm());`.
`console.log()` is a method (like a function) that prints an argument passed to it to the 'console' interface the programmer uses. So, the `myVector.norm()` method accesses the array inside of `myVector`, computes the norm, and hands it to `console.log` to be printed out, resulting in something to the effect of `3.7416573867739413855837487323165` being printed to the console.

Comment: @Brad, sounds weird and interesting. What does the "log" part of console.log mean?

Comment: @goblin if you wanted to make the vector return something more user friendly, you could easily add the fluff you described (while still using console.log in this example for simplicity's sake) with something like `console.log("my norm is " + myVector.norm())` (the + being concatenation here, not addition), and set that up to be triggered by some kind of user input being matched with the phrase `"I want to know your norm"`. This could be either set up as a one-time event, or a piece of repeatable code attached to the vector prototype as a method (like maybe `Vector.prototype.printNorm()` )!

Comment: @goblin just log as in 'to record'. And sorry, I didn't clarify that was using JavaScript, so that's specific to that language. Different languages have different ways of logging information to the console. For instance, in C++/C# they use a structure that looks like `cout << "this string will be output to the console" << endl;`. When the creators of JavaScript were setting up the language, they created an object called 'console' containing most operations pertinent to the console, with the log method containing specifically whatever operations they used to print information to the console.

Comment: @goblin the ideas driving the use of such object and method structures like `console.log()` are primarily 1) to hide complexity (i.e. all the code that makes `console.log()` work) behind simple interfaces (like `console.log()`), and 2) to store commonly reused code in a way that is easily accessed.

Comment: @Brad, possibly a very hard question to answer in these tiny comment boxes, but why not just apply functions to entities, like mathematicians do? Like `norm(x)` or `norm([1, 2, 3])` or whatever.

Comment: You absolutely can, and that's the basis for the functional programming, but object-oriented programming builds on that by associating functions to objects as 'methods'. The thing is, objects are less 'entities' as you are thinking about them, and more definitions of scope. This becomes important especially when creating multiple instances from the same object prototype (like a template). The object itself is not an entity per se, but a container that can hold an entity, as well as any useful operations.

Comment: @Brad, okay. Sounds interesting. I mean, I don't really get the point of it - but good to learn new ways of thinking, I suppose - so I'll try to keep an open mind.

Comment: @goblin here is a simplified version of the vector class I created for that exercise I was working on for reference. It'll look a little crazy because of the formatting in the comments here. Don't mind the `function` keyword at the start, that's used for setting up prototype objects as well as defining more classic functions. 
`var Vector = function (components) {
  this.arr = components;
  this.dot = v => compareLength(v, vec => this.arr.map((x,i) => x*vec.getArr()[i]).reduce((a,b) => a+b));
  this.norm = () => this.arr.length < 1 ? 0 : this.dot(this));
};`

Comment: @goblin most simply, the point is just to reduce the amount of writing required to express complex instructions, and to make such instructions repeatable with little additional code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40588/discussion-between-brad-and-goblin).

Comment: For anyone reading this discussion that's interested in learning further about Object-oriented Programming, I recommend checking out http://eloquentjavascript.net/06_object.html

Comment: @Brad, thanks for the link. I'll check it out when I have more time.

Comment: @Brad, honestly I don't think using OO concepts to study vectors makes very much sense. The whole point of OO, if I understand correctly, is that I can have a personOne object with a private "position in $\mathbb{R}^3$" field, and a personTwo object with a private "position in $\mathbb{R}^3$" field, and I can write personOne.walkNorth() to get personOne change their internal position field such that now they're one step further north. All well and good, but mathematical entities aren't objects like this; I cannot tell a vector to "walkNorth()", because that would be a new vector....

Comment: The vectors $[1,2,3]$ and $[2,2,3]$ are *different* vectors. They aren't equal. So you fundamentally *cannot* hand a vector an instruction to change its internal state, because nothing in math ever changes; if you change something, its a different thing. Ergo, if you hand a vector an instruction to "walkNorth()", its not a vector, its a person (animal, thing, whatever). But anyway, its no longer a mathematical entity at all; its some kind of a "computational entity." The whole "everything isan object" aspect of OO makes imo very little sense -- objects aren't the right viewpoint on abstract...

Comment: ...mathematical objects, since these are timeless -- they never, ever change.

Comment: @goblin Mathematically, what you're saying is correct. The thing is, the vector held within the Vector object isn't intended to be a constant. In practice it's a variable containing a set of values representing a specific vector. In theory, and this is the part that I hope is relevant to your comments, it's a pointer to a vector. When one refers to 'changing the vector', you're not seeking to change a mathematical constant, but rather what the 'Vector' object is referencing. One of the potential applications would be if you're creating a simulation with different entities existing at...

Comment: ...different coordinates in space, and you were using such vectors as a means of assigning their positions. The entities would likely be objects themselves containing their information and relevant functions, including a vector object that indicates their present location.

Comment: @Brad, then why not rephrase: the mysterious-sounding "I'm currently working with a computer science problem that requires me to build vectors that can return their own norms" becomes the more reasonable-sounding "I'm currently working with a computer science problem that requires me to build vector containers that can return the norms of the vector contained therein."

Comment: The next chapter of Eloquent JavaScript actually works through a simple world simulation project that does just that, using simpler x,y vectors on a 2D grid. That might be an interesting read for seeing how this kind of structure can be used in programming! http://eloquentjavascript.net/07_elife.html

Comment: @goblin Because I've put about 9000% more thought into this comments discussion than I did into writing the original post, haha. My only intent was to say that "hey, I'm working on this cs thing, but a math thing came up and I want to ask mathy people what this is used for in math, because I have very little notion of what it is beyond being asked to compute it."

Comment: @Brad, thanks for the link. Fair enough re 9000%

Comment: @goblin :D sorry for any confusion!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Norms are a measure of distance. One has different ways to define what is the distance between points in multiple dimensions, which collapse to the usual notion of the absolute value in 1D.

in particular, Euclidean distance is defined by the 2-norm,
$$
\left\| \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ \vdots \\ x_k \end{pmatrix} \right\|_2
 = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^k x_i^2}
$$

There are others, of which the 1-norm
$$
\left\| \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ \vdots \\ x_k \end{pmatrix} \right\|_1
 = \sum_{i=1}^k \left|x_i\right|
$$
and the infinity norm
$$
\left\| \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ \vdots \\ x_k \end{pmatrix} \right\|_\infty
 = \max_{1 \le i \le k} \left\{|x_i|\right\}
$$
are the most useful.

You are welcome to read up more on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)), [lecture notes](https://www.math.usm.edu/lambers/mat610/sum10/lecture2.pdf).

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I did look at the Wikipedia link, but it was a bit over my head at this point. I appreciate you distilling it so well! Having looked at the Wikipedia again after reading your explanation, it makes quite a bit more sense.